# How to do normalization of data for interpolation with perceptron?

Tags: c++, neural-network, perceptron

I'm trying to do a normalization of data for a polinomial interpolation with perceptron, I'm using the following formula:

[image: 1]

Where:
xi is a data point (x1, x2…xn).

x̄ is the sample mean.

s is the sample standard deviation.

and Z is my new value of input for the perceptron.

I'm programming in C ++, and plotting graph with freeglut.

My function for normalize:

```cpp
vector<double> Perceptron::normalizar(double x) { 
    vector<double> aux;
    aux.push_back(1.0);

    for (unsigned i = 1; i < pesos.size(); i++) {
        double t = (pow(x,i) - means[i]) / devianation[i];
        aux.push_back(t);
    }
    return aux;
}
```

The problem is: before I did the normalization, the polynomial was converging to the points.
[image]

But after normalization, the polynomial is converging to other points, and I do not know where it is converging.
[image]

The formula for the polynomial would be as follows (with W being the weights of the perceptron):
[image]

So I used a mean formula for each value of x.

[image]

[image]

[image]

See the code:

```
void Perceptron::mean(Points P) { //P is a struct with all x and y values of the points.
means.clear(); //vector that stores the means
for (unsigned i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++) {
    double m = 0;
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < P.size(); j++) {
        m += pow(P[i].x, i);
    }
    means.push_back(m / P.size());
}
```

}

```
void Perceptron::deviation(Points P) {
deviations.clear(); //vector that stores the deviations
for (unsigned i = 0; i < weights.size(); i++) {
    double sd = 0;
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < P.size(); j++) {
        sd += pow(pow(P[j].x, i) - means[i], 2);
    }
    deviations.push_back(sqrt(sd / P.size()));
}
```

}

Comment: How do you calculate `means` and `devianation` ? Moreover, the polynomial should converge to the `z[i]` , not to the `x[i]`.

Comment: I've edited my question, to answer you.  I need to know if after the perceptron calculates its weights with normalized data, it would be possible to return my original variable, X.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what `z` is. I suppose now you are speaking of normalisation by deviation.

Comment: You're right, the polynomial must converge to z [i], not to x [i], which I do not know is how to redraw my polynomial now.